# ssrs reports in AX 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on `ssrs reports` in `ax 2012` and have a query.

The requirement is to calculate the sum of `amountcur` value from `CustTrans` table based on the month for the current year and previous year for all the months separately.Date to be taken is `TransDate`
Can anyone please tell me the logic and where to write the code as I have made this report using query.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a group based on date. You can create a formula for the month and group based on this formula. Probably you would like do something like for each month grouping in Crystal.